# Check if product prices includes tax in Woocommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, tax

How can you programmatically check if a product's price includes tax? I checked the WC_Product reference, but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: do you know it's original value before tax?  Because if you know **original price** then it's just math.  If you know price and tax rate even better.

Comment: There it took me 3 minutes.  `WC_Order_Item_Product::get_subtotal_tax()`, well this is where I would start at least or something similar. `WC_Order_Item_Product::get_total_tax()` or `WC_Order_Item_Product::get_taxes()`  https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#262-270

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will simply use the dedicated conditional function [`wc_prices_include_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_prices_include_tax.html#344-351) in an **`IF`** statement:

```
if( wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
    // Price include tax
} else {
    // Price doesn't include tax
}
```

> It will check if taxes are enabled in Woocommerce and if your product prices general setting are including tax or not.

For example [`wc_prices_include_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_prices_include_tax.html#344-351) is used by  [`wc_get_price_including_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_including_tax.html#895-953) a `WC_Product` price function *(not a method)*,
used herself in [`wc_get_price_to_display()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_to_display.html#989-1007) price function when products prices need to be displayed including taxes in product pages…

If product prices need to be displayed excluding taxes in product pages, [`wc_get_price_to_display()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_to_display.html#989-1007) will use [`wc_get_price_excluding_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_to_display.html#955-987)

> [`wc_get_price_to_display()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_to_display.html#989-1007), [`wc_get_price_including_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_including_tax.html#895-953) and [`wc_get_price_excluding_tax()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_to_display.html#955-987) have 2 arguments:
>
> • `$product` *(mandatory)* the `WC_Product` object 
>   • `$args` *(optional)* an array containing the product price and the quantity

Related: [Display Woocommerce product price with and without tax and tax amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227730/woocommerce-display-price-included-tax-on-product-page)

---

On Cart, Checkout and Orders there is another general setting that allow you to display prices with or without taxes. You can use the following to check if prices are displayed with or without taxes:

```
if( get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' ) ) {
    // Prices displayed including tax
}
```

Order items related:

- [Get tax rate used in an order for one product and for shipping in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852972/get-tax-rate-used-in-an-order-for-one-product-and-for-shipping-in-woocommerce/46854867#46854867)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)
- [Get some order and order items data in Woocommerce emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748956/get-some-order-and-order-items-data-in-woocommerce-emails/51749779#51749779)

Answer (score 0):

Well product will not tell you if someone paid sales tax. For that you need something involving an order.

Something that has orders and products, something like this class:

```
WC_Order_Item_Product
```

For reference

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#262-270

This has at least 3 relevant methods:

```
//Get subtotal tax.
WC_Order_Item_Product::get_subtotal_tax();

//Get total tax.
WC_Order_Item_Product::get_total_tax();

Get taxes.
WC_Order_Item_Product::get_taxes();
```

Note these are not "static" I just like the way it looks, and it's common on the PHP document page to do it this way :-p

Now how you get there from where you are, I don't know. Meaning how you get one of these mystical `WC_Order_Item_Product` objects.

Good Luck!