# Get tax rates for product on manual order creation in WooCommerce admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rate, tax

I'm trying to get all product tax rates from order items in WooCommerce orders.

Based on [Get tax rate used in an order for one product and for shipping in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852972/get-tax-rate-used-in-an-order-for-one-product-and-for-shipping-in-woocommerce/46854867#46854867) answer code, I built a loop for order items:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_value) {
    $item_data = $item_value->get_data();

    $product_id = $item_value['product_id'];
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $wc_product = $item_value->get_product(); // prodotto in WooCommerce
    $sku = '';
    if(!empty($wc_product))
        $sku = $wc_product->get_sku();
    $product_type = $item_value->get_type();

    if ($item_data['variation_id'] !== 0) {
        $variation = $item_data['variation_id'];
        $var_data = new \WC_Product_Variation($variation);
        $var_attr = implode(', ', $var_data->get_variation_attributes());
    }

    $tax_rates = \WC_Tax::get_rates($item_data['tax_class']);
    if (!empty($tax_rates)) {
        $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates);
    } 
    
    $rateId = key($tax_rates);
    $rate = \WC_Tax::get_rate_percent_value($rateId);   
    $rateDescription = \WC_Tax::get_rate_label($rateId);
    
    
    /* in questo array ho tutti i dati che mi servono,
    *  sotto la chiave data raggruppo item_data
    */ 
    $order_items_data[] = array(
      'product_id' => $product_id,
      'sku' => $sku,
      'product_type' => $product_type,
      'variation_attr' => $var_attr,
      'price' => $fixnum($item_data['subtotal'] / $item_data['quantity'], 6),
      'discount' => $item_data['subtotal'] - $item_data['total'],
      'tax_rate' => $rate,
      'tax_description' => $rateDescription,
      'tax_id' => $rateId,
      'data' => $item_data
   );
}
```

This code does its work correctly when the order is added on site frontend.
When I add a new order by admin I get an empty `$tax_rates` array, that's my issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a solution:

after this snippet

```
$tax_rates = \WC_Tax::get_rates($item_data['tax_class']);
    if (!empty($tax_rates)) {
        $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates);
    } 
    
    $rateId = key($tax_rates);
    $rate = \WC_Tax::get_rate_percent_value($rateId);   
    $rateDescription = \WC_Tax::get_rate_label($rateId);
```

I added these lines:

```
if (empty($rateId)) {
    $usedRate = array_filter($item_data['taxes']['total']);
    $rateId = key($usedRate);
    $rate = \WC_Tax::get_rate_percent_value($rateId);
    $rateDescription = \WC_Tax::get_rate_label($rateId);
}
```

That is because `$item_data['taxes']['total']` array contains an empty value if the product is using another tax id.

I hope it's all clear