# WooCommerce: Get order totals only from items with reduced tax rate

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, tax

I want to export only the totals from items with a reduced tax rate.

For example, I have 2 items with a reduced tax rate and one with the normal tax rate:

- Item A: 100€  -  5,00€ reduced tax   -  105,00€ total
- Item B: 50€   -  2,50€ reduced tax   -  52,50€ total
- Item C: 100€  -  19,00€ normal tax   -  119,00€ total

I now want the totals from Item A and B. In this case a combined value of 157,50€.

I found a [code snippet](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/) to get the total tax amounts with class:

```
// Get the WC_Order instance Object from the Order ID (if needed)
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Output the tax rows in a table
echo '<table>';
foreach ( $order->get_tax_totals() as $rate_code => $tax ) {
    $tax_rate_id  = $tax->rate_id;
    $tax_label    = $tax->label;
    $tax_amount   = $tax->amount;
    $tax_f_amount = $tax->formatted_amount;
    $compound     = $tax->is_compound;
    echo '<tr><td>' . $tax_label  . ': </td><td>' . $tax_f_amount . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

But that code gives me all tax classes. Is there any way to get only one?

Here's what I'm doing right now (excerpt):

```
$custom_order_total_tax         = $custom_order_data['total_tax'];
$custom_order_total             = $custom_order_data['total'];      
$custom_order_subtotal          = $order->get_subtotal();
```

There is nothing I could use in the `$order` variable.

I guess I need to go through all items of the order. But how could I select these items by tax rate?

I found something [here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/):

```
// Get and Loop Over Order Items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
   $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
   $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
   $product = $item->get_product();
   $name = $item->get_name();
   $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
   $subtotal = $item->get_subtotal();
   $total = $item->get_total();
   $tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax();
   $taxclass = $item->get_tax_class();
   $taxstat = $item->get_tax_status();
   $allmeta = $item->get_meta_data();
   $somemeta = $item->get_meta( '_whatever', true );
   $type = $item->get_type();
}
```

But the tax rate is not part of it. So I guess I need a second array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the tax class of the order items look here:

- [Get tax rate used in an order for one product and for shipping in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852972/get-tax-rate-used-in-an-order-for-one-product-and-for-shipping-in-woocommerce)

Then you can create a custom function that **sums the totals of the order items based on a specified tax class**.

There are *two parameters* of the function:

- **`$order_id`**: the id of the order from which you want to get the totals
- **`$tax_class`**: the tax class to use as a filter *(by default "reduced-rate" is set)*

So:

```
// gets the total of the order items by tax class
function get_total_order_items_by_tax_class( $order_id, $tax_class = 'reduced-rate' ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // initializes the total of the order items
    $total = 0;
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $order_item ) {
        // if the product tax class is equal to "$tax_class"
        if ( $tax_class == $order_item['tax_class'] ) {
            // sum the total
            $total += $order_item['total'];
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

**USAGE**

If you want to get the sum of the totals of the order items with the *order id* **`60`** according to the **`reduced-rate`** *tax class* you can do it as follows:

```
$total = get_total_order_items_by_tax_class( 60 );
```

If you want to filter products based on the **`standard`** tax class you can use:

```
$total = get_total_order_items_by_tax_class( 60, '' );
```

Because the `standard` tax class slug is empty.

*The code has been tested and works.*

Comment: thank you! works fine ;-) Just one last quesiton: If I try to use "standard" as tax class, the code always results in 0,00€. Is "standard" the wrong class?

Comment: mille grazie Vincenzo!